# Debugging i/o streams: watching for change

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, io

While debugging I'd like to watch my input streams to tell when they've received data (and are ready for reading). I know the Eclipse debugger highlights changed variable values, but can this also work for values within values?

My situation: I have a list of BufferedReaders. Where exactly do I navigate to to watch for change (by expanding my BufferedReaders in the side pane)? Or is there a way to watch the top level? My i/o streams are attached to sockets if that makes any difference.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "how deep down?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that it is not possible to get the highlighting on the 'changed' readers automatically from Eclipse. The highlighting is reserved for changes of the variables themselves. In the case of objects a 'change' means that they would point to a different object, and that is not the case: your variables all continue to reference the very same BufferedReader instances. Descending through the class tree will eventually get you to the information you are after, but doing that for more than one variable at the same time is quite painful.

If the actual number of Readers you have to look after is not too large, the following might help you: you can subclass BufferedReader and override toString() so that it outputs the information which is useful for you. That way, you see that information whenever you click on the actual variable in the 'Variables' tab, or when you use the arrow keys to highlight it. Not as good as Eclipse's automatic highlighting, but perhaps good enough?

Here's a simple example. Put a breakpoint on the 'System.out.println(in.read())' line and have a look at the 'in' variable in the debugger. First time, you will see 'available: 34'. On the next occasions, you will see 'available: 0' because the BufferedReader has already fully read the input stream, and all subsequent reads will originate from the BufferedReader's buffer.

```
public class InputStreamDebugTest {

public static class MyReader extends BufferedReader {

    private final InputStream in;

    public MyReader(InputStream in) {
        super(new InputStreamReader(in));
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        try {
            return "available: " + in.available();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    MyReader in = new MyReader(new ByteArrayInputStream("Just some minor text for debugging".getBytes()));
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(in.read());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Cool! Good enough idea for now.